# Помогите составить регулярное выражение для поиска по шаблону

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день.

Есть текст

```
TOTALT

< Kommentar: Som vanligt blir
Lexus-hybriden törstig i våra tester.
Mercedes imponerar på väg.

8
7
```

Как мне найти только фразу от "Som" до "väg.".
Причем текст я не знаю, т.е. я знаю только

```
TOTALT

< Kommentar:
```

и знаю, что после искомой фразу идет переход на строку (2 раза) и потом какое-то число.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
TOTALT\n\n< Kommentar: ([\s\S]+?)(?=\n\n\d+)
```

и брать первую группу.